# Mirroring in SQL Server image datatype support

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to mirror my sql server 2005 and I read that filestream is not supported in 2008 and I thought image data type might be in this category so my question is :
if I mirror a database which has a table that contains a column of image datatype will it be mirrored successfully ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Database mirroring does not support FILESTREAM. A FILESTREAM filegroup cannot be created on the principal server. Database mirroring cannot be configured for a database that contains FILESTREAM filegroups.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895334.aspx#DatabaseMirroring
```